# Logging in tomcat doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, logging, log4j2

I have fullproject based on spring with using some Controllers, DAO and other web application elements. And now i want to configure log4j2. I do it:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

create log4j2.xml in src/main/resources folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <logger name="com.myproject" level="INFO" />
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

and then i create class with main(String [] args) method which have to output some info logs:

```
public class MainClass{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MainClass.class.getName());
        logger.info("Entering Log4j Example.");


    }
}
```

for run application i use:

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3.2</version>
          <configuration>
              <mainClass>com.myproject.MainClass</mainClass>
          </configuration>
```

And all it i do in redactor, which has own console. And deploy it with tomcat7 maven plugin.

Please say me, do i make it all in correct way or wrong. And if in correct when i can see result of these logs, because in redactor console i don't see and in tomcat logs too

Comment: What does tomcat have to do with anything in your question?

Comment: I wrote 'I have fullproject based on spring with using some Controllers, DAO and other web application elements' and here i wrote only snippet which can implement

Comment: 'main' functions aren't relevant to tomcat in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the destination appender:

```xml
<Loggers>
  <Logger name="com.myproject" level="INFO">
    <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE"/>
  </Logger>
</Loggers>
```

---

By the way, you have confused a *standalone application* with a *web application*. In Tomcat, you need a web application with servlets, jsp's, etc. You may want to see [*How To Create A Web Application Project With Maven*](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/).

Comment: Don't i have public main() method here with typical web application?

Comment: in this tutorial http://www.journaldev.com/2552/spring-restful-web-service-example-with-json-jackson-and-client-program author created RestTemplate in main().

Comment: No you never have a main function. Or, to be exact, nothing will call it.